# Is it a bad action to use Dependent Query inside a Query with LIMIT 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

I read a lot that using `Dependent Query` is bad and i should use `JOIN`s, I have a code which JOINs a lot of tables together, like the following

```
SELECT a.a, b.b, c.c, d.d FROM
tablea a
JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id
JOIN tablec c ON a.id = c.id
JOIN tabled d ON a.id = d.id
WHERE a.id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Right now i can use a Dependent Query and Select a value from another table with the`a.a` like this

```
SELECT a.a, b.b, c.c, d.d, (SELECT e FROM tablee WHERE id = a.a) AS e FROM
tablea a
JOIN tableb b ON a.id = b.id
JOIN tablec c ON a.id = c.id
JOIN tabled d ON a.id = d.id
WHERE a.id = 1
LIMIT 1
```

In this case, Do i use the easiest to read and edit for me `Dependent Query`, Or do i just stick with `JOIN`s?

Comment: It's probably better to use a `JOIN` most of the time. It's just more readable.

Comment: @tadman For me i find the `DQ` more readable in my long queries with a lot of different `WHERE` conditions for each `DQ`, But my concern here is if using `DQ` is still bad on performance more than `JOIN` even with `LIMIT 1`

Comment: DQ means ["Dairy Queen"](http://dairyqueen.com) to me, so try and avoid that acronym. It's just a subquery, nothing special. `JOIN` might seem more difficult to understand at first, but it's more specific, it establishes the link between table A and table B in very concrete terms. Your subquery here is isn't as elegant. With a `JOIN` you can also specify left, right, inner, outer, to get very specific results.

Comment: @tadman So it is better/works if i used `JOIN tablee e ON a.a = e.id` ? Since i never tried to use a `SELECT`ed value`(a.a)` in `ON` before in the same Query.

Comment: Consider how cluttered and confusing your query would be with 10 different subqueries versus one query with 10 different join clauses. The joins themselves can be understood one at a time, whereas the subqueries are often one giant tangle of confusion since they can appear in some very odd places if you're not disciplined about keeping things organized.

Comment: @tadman if possible, Can you show me how to replace my `Dependent Query` with a `JOIN` query? Since i tried to use `JOIN tablee e ON a.a = e.id` but the query failed.

Comment: "Failed" means what? You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @tadman my mistake, selected wrong column, now i'm more open about `JOIN`s, And i find it impressive that it makes me make use less `INDEX`es

Comment: You'll still need indexes on all the related columns involved, so don't think you're avoiding that. `EXPLAIN` is useful for showing index weak spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read a lot that using Dependent Query is bad and i should use JOINs,

This is misguidance.  Certainly, `JOIN`s are very powerful and should not be discouraged.  The SQL optimizer understands `JOIN`s and they are quite powerful and easy to read.

The does not mean the correlated subqueries are wrong.  For instance, yours is fine -- even from a performance perspective -- if you have an index on `tablee(id, e)`.  In fact, that might be the most optimal way of writing the query.  Writing the query with a `join` would probably generate a similar execution plan, though.

If you did use a `join`, you would need a `left join` for the same semantics.

There are some situations where correlated subqueries are *better* in terms of performance.  The exact specifics might vary by database, so there are no rules that are "general" across all databases.

My one very strong piece of advice is to qualify *all* column names when you reference more than on table in a query.  So, you should be writing:

```
SELECT a.a, b.b, c.c, d.d,
       (SELECT e.e FROM tablee e WHERE e.id = a.a) AS e
FROM tablea a . . .
```

Comment: Does qualifing the names puts less work And make it faster? Also i understood that `Dependent Queries` are bad in un`LIMITED` Queries because it works as an individual query for each row in the table the main query fetches, That what makes me think that there is not different between `JOIN` amd `Dependent Query` because of `LIMIT 1`,And yes, my indexes are fully set for best performance i can have.

Comment: @Toleo . . . When an appropriate index is available, correlated subqueries can be the most efficient way to write certain queries.